# Scala type mismatch issue

Tags: scala, recursion

I am currently trying to learn Scala so I have decided to write a simple function to check if the parenthesis are balanced in some expression. My code is as follows

```
def balance(chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {

  def find(par: Char, list: List[Char]): Boolean = {
    if(list.isEmpty) return false
    if(list.head == par) {
      return true
    } else {
      find(par, list.tail)
    }
  }

  if(chars.isEmpty) {
    return false
  }
  if(chars.head == '(') {
    if(!find(')', chars.tail)) {
      return false
    }
  } else {
    balance(chars.tail)
  }
}
```

However  I am getting  `type mismatch, required: Boolean, found: Unit` on the line `if(!find(')', chars.tail))`. How is this possible?I think the `find` recursion function will always return a `Boolean`. Btw I don't know if my solution is correct, I just got stuck on this exception.

Comment: What if the condition inside the `if` is not satisfied? If you don't provide an else part the compiler will infer `Unit` because he doesn't know what to do if the `if` fails.

Comment: Is the coursera course running again?

Comment: Yes, it is. Today is a deadline for first assignment so hurry up :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if/else` is an expression statement in scala, so it returns a value.

Leaving out the `else` branch, makes the compiler to infer `Unit` for the whole expression, since it cannot produce anything else.

You have to return a `Boolean` from every possible branch, in order to match the method return type of `Boolean`.

You can fix your code by doing:

```
if(chars.head == '(' && !find(')', chars.tail)) {
  return false
} else {
  balance(chars.tail)
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I already did that thanks to @Ende Neu comment. Thank you for more comprehensive explanation!